# Isolating powered-off raspberry-pi gpio pin from rest of circuit (that is powered on)

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio

First of all sorry for the long title, I hope it is descriptive enough.

I am planning to connect a TSSOP4838 (IR Receiver) to a Raspberry PI GPIO input pin. My problem is that the TSSOP4838 will (at times) be powered on while the PI is powered off. The TSSOP4838 has an open-collector output with a 33k pullup. The same output will be connected to an input pin of an ATTiny85 (also powered on). As far as I can tell this is going to be a problem, as the output of the TSSOP4838 (normally high when idle) will feed power to the PI through the input pin clamp diode. Of course the power won't be enough to bring the PI up due to the 33k pullup.

My question is how to properly isolate the PI input pin while it is powered off, so that the TSSOP4838 output can still be read by the ATTiny and yet when the PI is powered on be able to read it from the PI as well.

I have not yet tried anything in fear of smoking my PI.

All supplies are 3.3v so no level shifting required.

Edit:
Would a simple level shifter like this work?

[Simple MOSFET level shifter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHuPW.png)

RPi side would go on the left (low voltage side). This would also take care of minor differences in supply voltage. My worry is that if RPi output is not HiZ when powered off, it could bring the level down to 0 on the other side.

Comment: This question might find a better home at http://electronics.stackexchange.com. stackoverflow is for programming related questions. Hint: if your question involves a device which is *powered off* programmers will be unlikely to help ;). Not a bad question though - moderators might be able to help you move it

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I am new to stackoverflow. Now on to find how to move my question to the proper section/site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you aren't going to smoke your pi with 3.3v on a gpio pin... I am guessing that you can hold power on a gpio pin with the pi off and it will be in a high impedance mode and not affect anything... you can check the impedance with a multimeter.

if it isn't in high impedance mode then you should worry about power consumption rather than burning it up...

but probably your design is somewhat flawed anyway and you should be going through a transistor or diode or some combination of those things anyway (just guessing without a diagram)

Comment: I am also assuming your 3.3v source is the same... not different, because the voltage difference between one 3.3v source and another could be huge (they will both be 3.3v from pos-neg but across the 2 circuits it could be many volts between the 2 positives, etc)

Comment: I kind of figured I won't smoke it (its only 100uA) but wanted to be on the safe side. You also right that the design is flawed, hence my question.

Comment: No, the 3.3v will not be the same. The PI derives its own 3.3v from the 5v supply, the rest of the circuit will derive 3.3v independently (otherwise it couldn't possibly be on while the PI is off) from the same 5v supply. They will however share a common ground so the difference would be relatively small (in the 0.1-0.2v range, certainly not several volts)

Comment: I know that is fine if at least one side is a battery, not sure if they are both transformers...

Comment: Actually a switching power supply will provide 5v. From that an AMS1117 will output 3.3v. The same 5v will be supplying the PI through a relay. This shouldn't be a problem when both circuits are powered on (0.1v difference would draw 3uA through the 33k pullup).

Comment: I did some tests using a 10k resistor to isolate the GPIO pin from the IR receiver and the ATTiny. When RPi is powered off and pin is driven high (3.3v) through the resistor it hardly draws 100nA to ground. It turns out RPi GPIO is in High-Z state while powered off.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a low VF (voltage forward) diode in series with each input with the cathode connected to the 4838. set the PI GPIO in pull up mode and it should work just fine.